# when cookie sets it sets for all system browsers

Tags: php

I'm having a small challenge, trying to set cookie in php.
If a user should log in with Mozilla Firefox, and the Cookie is set for mozilla Firefox browser, now if the same user now visits the same website with Google chrome, on the same system, it automatically logs in the user with the same Cookie that has already been set on Mozilla. What can i do, i want to just  set the cookie for each browser, so each different user can log in with different browsers.

This is my Code

```
$cookie_value = generateHash('somevalue');

$one_week = 60*60*24*7;

setcookie('http', $cookie_value, time() + $one_week, '/', 'domainname.com');
```

`domainname.com` is the website name.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. What could be the Cause?

Comment: If that’s happening, something is going really seriously wrong with your browsers. (Are you starting them up and importing cookies or something?)

Comment: You mean it's the browsers settings? Cause my browsers seems to be working fine, and this is the first i'm noticing something like this. Or perhaps the php code?

Comment: This sounds like a client-side configuration issue.  There's nothing in the HTTP spec that deals with cookie sharing across browsers.

Comment: Are you sure the generateHash function generates different hashes? If it throws out the same hash each time then you would get the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Sorry but cookies do not work this way, there is no cross-browsers exchange of cookies. That is simply not possible.

Comment: You have probably tested using the same user in all your browsers. It just looks like its copying cross-browser, `but its not`. Reset cookies for that domain in all your browsers and start the test again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Flash and Shared Objects but this is generally not a good idea.

Browsers not sharing cookies is expected behavior. Your users will be okay with this.